# Why does framework bundle path resolve to DerivedData build directory when targeting Simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator

#### Discrepancy

Xcode workspace sub-project product (Cocoa Touch Framework) is retrieved at runtime using `Bundle(for:)` local to the framework implementation.

When run on-device the returned path correctly points to the framework location in the application main bundle container (the Frameworks folder, where it was embedded):

```
/var/containers/Bundle/Application/[UUID]/App.app/Frameworks/Subproject.framework
```

But if the same application is built for Simulator, the framework bundle path resolves to the Build directory:

```
/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-gudzsitepqiiqaemjvwsloxbjobv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Subproject.framework
```

while the `Bundle.main.resourcePath` is correctly resolved to Simulator's container for the built application.

#### Issue

*The wrong, `DerivedData` path, is inaccessible at runtime because it is not a subdirectory of the application's bundle.* This makes it impossible to determine the filename required `GKScene` initializer dynamically at runtime when using Simulator.

#### Context

The following convenience initializer:

```swift
public extension GKScene {
    convenience init?(fileNamed filename: String, in bundle: Bundle) {
        guard
            let main = Bundle.main.resourcePath,
            let full = bundle.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "sks")?.path
        else {
            return nil
        }

        let relative = full.replacingOccurrences(of: "\(main)/", with: "")
        self.init(fileNamed: relative)
    }
}
```

is called like this:

```swift
GKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene", in: Bundle(for: type(of: self)))
```

The `Bundle(for: type(of: self))` call on Simulator will generate `DerivedData`-path and initializer will fail because it [requires](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gameplaykit/gkscene/1640935-init) the path to be a sub-path of the "Main Bundle"

Comment: [Previously people tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50729195/load-a-spritekit-scene-from-another-bundle/50731627) to load non-main-bundle assets using `NSKeyedUnarchiver` which seems dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When launching from Xcode, Xcode sets DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH and DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to the build products path such that linkage is resolved to your built frameworks when executing tests against them.

This has been the case for quite a long time in Xcode.  If you "finger launch" it from SpringBoard, you should get the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Is there an `#if`-style workaround that should be implemented in code?

Comment: Workaround for what?  There's not really a problem that needs working around... ?